# Crossbrowser JavaScript + DOM documentation

Tags: javascript, api, dom, documentation, reference

I'm already aware of some browser-specific DOM documentation out there (Gecko DOM Reference for Firefox, MSDN for Internet Explorer and, of course, the ECMA and W3C specs) but I wonder if someone has compiled a good API reference that covers all common browsers (Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari, Chrome...).

The [compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) by quirksmode.org are a good resource but they don't actually document stuff (it's not their purpose).

P.S. A downloadable format (such as CHM) would be a nice bonus ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.webdevout.net/) was one of the best sites but has not been updated since at least July. 2009, iirc.
You'll find a lot of useful info [here](http://gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/), too.

Comment: Well, there's not much out there to choose from I guess. I didn't know about Web Devout.

Answer (score 0):

For my JS documentation needs I use google search with appended `mdc` like this:

http://www.google.com/search?q=mdc+addeventlistener

The results come up with links to Mozilla Developer Center which is the best documented site ATM. It includes notes on browser incompatibilities too.